# How to make overflow auto working on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I tried on many browsers, Firefox, Safari, IE10, Android devices, all working fine. But when it turns into iOS devices, like iPads, iPhones, the overflow is not working.

```css
.card.with-scroll .card-body {
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

overflow: auto; and overflow: scroll; seem to work different on iOS and OS X. 
Try to use overflow: scroll; plus -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; on iOS and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-wekit-` before property to make it working in safari..!

```css
.card.with-scroll .card-body {
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  -webkit-overflow-y: auto; /* added css prefix for safari */
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

If this will not work apply to the parent element. for me, it worked.